# Append onload or redraw event functions dynamically in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I need to append onload or redraw event functions dynamically in Highcharts, I know make that in config step, like:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
   chart: {
       events: {
          load: function(event) {
              function1();
              function2();
              function3();
          },
          redraw: function(event) {
              functionA();
              functionB();
              functionC();
          }
       }        
    },
    xAxis: {
    },
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5]     
    }]
});
```

But I need do that after config the chart ('cause I don't have access to config chart step, the chart comes to my code by a wrapper) and I need to do something like this:

```
//The wrapper simulation
^
|
|
/////////////////////////////////////////
//$('#container').highcharts({         //
//    chart: {                         //
//       events: {                     //
//          load: function(event) {    //
//              function1();           //
//          },                         //
//          redraw: function(event) {  //
//              functionA();           //
//          }                          //< "I dont't have access to this code"
//       }                             //  
//    },                               //
//    xAxis: {                         //
//    },                               // 
//    series: [{                       //
//        data: [29.9, 71.5]           //   
//    }]                               // 
//});                                  //
/////////////////////////////////////////

//I only have the container id in my hands, I can get the highchart object:
$('#container').highcharts();

//And I need to do something like this:
appendOnLoadEvent(function2);
appendOnLoadEvent(function3);

appendOnRedrawEvent(functionB);
appendOnRedrawEvent(functionC);
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest way is to create the events as you described in the first example, and in those functions execute all necesary event handlers from an array.

Something like:

```
  var redrawCallbacks = [];

  $(...).highcharts({
  chart: {
      events: {
          redraw: function(event) {
              for (var i = 0; i < redrawCallbacks.length; ++i) redrawCallbacks[i].call(this, event);
          }
      }
  }});
```

See full example at: http://jsfiddle.net/5S6hF/2/

**UPDATE**
Assuming you are using the default jQuery adapter, you can define events later with:

```
$(chart).on('redraw', function(){ alert('new event handler'); });
```

See demo at http://jsfiddle.net/5S6hF/6/

Comment: In my particular case, I don't have all functions defined before create the chart, I already defined some functions when create, and I can't overwrite those functions :(

Comment: ...And Is not me who create the chart, this chart come to me already defined by a wrapper, this is the big problem :(

Comment: But what is wrong with solution provided by lionel? As you can see it just works. Define two arrays of functions, redraw and load callbacks should loop over that arrays and call functions. If you add more callbacks to that arrays, chart automatically call all of them.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have access to set anything in "create chart step", the chart comes to me already defined by a wrapper. it's not my code that creates the chart :(

Comment: Lionel, your last code it's exactly what I need, but when I change the 'redraw' to 'load', this code doesn't work, you know why?

Comment: I think it's 'cause the chart it's already loaded before define the event function. Can I force the chart reload after define my functions?

Comment: Yes its because the chart already loaded, and you can force a load event again with `$(chart).trigger('load');`, but that can raise some other problems, because all load event handler will run again, and some maybe counting on them running only once. I see a possible workaround, test for `chart.hasRendered`. If its true, the chart is loaded, you should call all onload handlers manually, like `myEventHandler.call(chart)`. Otherwise, add all handlers like you do with redraw.

Comment: Thanks for your attention dude, you save my day

Answer (score 1):

For Highchart 4.2, you have to use the addEvent method to add event to chart object.
Follow the below code, first retrieve highchart object and then add redraw/load event to it

```
var chart1= Highcharts.charts[0];
Highcharts.addEvent(chart1,'redraw', function(){alert('hi');});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add callback (like event load), where you can also add redraw events. You need ot do this before creating chart.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/5S6hF/5/

```
var redrawCallbacks = [];

function appendOnRedrawEvent(callback) {
    redrawCallbacks.push(callback);
}

var loadCallbacks = [];

function appendOnLoadEvent(callback) {
    loadCallbacks.push(callback);
}

appendOnLoadEvent(function () {
    alert('onload added dynamically');
});

H = Highcharts;
H.Chart.prototype.callbacks.push(function (chart) {
    for (var i = 0; i < loadCallbacks.length; ++i) loadCallbacks[i].call(this, event);

    H.addEvent(chart, 'redraw', function (e) {
        for (var i = 0; i < redrawCallbacks.length; ++i) redrawCallbacks[i].call(this, event);
    });
});

//create chart
$('#container').highcharts({
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5]
    }]
});



appendOnRedrawEvent(function () {
    alert('redraw added later');
});
```

Comment: This will add the event handlers to all Chart instances created in that page. If you have more than one chart on a page, you may get unwanted results.

Comment: @lionel - yes, that's true. In case of more charts on a site, you need to add some if-else to check if that chart should execute callback. Just to be clear: to achieve what you need you should been using `chart.events.event`, about solution is just a workaround. If your wrapper prevents you from doing so, remove that wrapper and use  pure Highcharts library.

Comment: I don't know why, but it didn't work here, maybe my browser or another thing is causing this