# HighCharts (HighMaps) - Function to resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

My question is simple (I think)

I have a DIV with class "container" that I'm using to be my Map. This awesome plugin (Highcharts) is responsive, but it only resize when the window resize.

I was needing 'force' it resize without change my window. Explaining better, when I click in a State, I'll show another DIV on it side, so, for me show it, I need to resize my "container", but the map only calculate the size of DIV on resize window, as i said. I only need to do the map resize in my function to show the other DIV.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="info-maps"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
.info-maps{
    width: 50%;
    display: none;
    float: left;
}
.info-maps-show{
    display: block !important;
}
.container-resize{
    width: 50% !important;
}
```

Javascript (jQuery):

```
$(**State**).click(function(){
    $('.container').addClass('container-resize');
    $('.info-maps').addClass('info-maps-show');

    //Here I need to do the map resize :)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force redraw as part of Highcharts callbacks. A great explanation here: [Append onload or redraw event functions dynamically in Highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22336432/append-onload-or-redraw-event-functions-dynamically-in-highcharts)

Comment: Oh, Thanks man! It help me. 
If someone whant the resolution, here is it:

`$('#container').highcharts().setSize(
    $('#container').width(), 
    $('#container').height(),
    false
);`

It's only put it on **//Here I need to do the map resize :)**